# TextView setScaleX()/setScaleY() and setTextIsSelectable(true) selection

Tags: android, textview, zooming, selection, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have TextView and want to use `setScaleX()/setScaleY()` to make the text zoomable. But when I try to select some text by calling `someTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);` and TextView has zoom other than 1.0f the text selection markers apprear in wrong place, it seems that the selection is shown in the old place of selected text.

Please see screenshots

[image: NO ZOOM]
[image: ZOOM 1.2f]

Can anyone help me with this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: it should not be zoomed if u given the setScaleX(1.0f) . and m not sure about it not maintain the selected position . have tried it on api level 14 it works perfect for me !!

Comment: API Level 14 means Android 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, unfortunately I do not own any Ice Cream Sandwich device to check this, but I need this working on Honeycomb devices. And it does not work on Honeycomb devices Android 3.2(API 13), Android 3.1.x(API 12) and Android 3.0.x(API 11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that we recently fixed internally. Consider changing the font size instead.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give any directions, comments or example how can I fix this for Android 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your code, but I assume that you didn't make it selectable after zooming? That's all I can say without seeing the code.

Comment: No you are not right. The problem persists when I make selection after zooming or before zooming, sorry but I've checked this already.

Comment: I also added sample project. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any reason for change the textview's scales instead the font size?

Changing the textview scales is useful when you have images inside.

This example show's how change the textview font size:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14306988/2157878